# What will the output voltage be from this inverter when supplied 9 or 18 V?

Tags: voltage, inverter, output

This is a circuit of DC to AC inverter I found online on a [web site](https://www.elprocus.com/dc-to-ac-converter-circuit-working-applications/).

Can anyone explain what will be output voltage if I give it 9 or 18 V from a DC battery?

[image]

Comment: The schematic is abysmal. 2N2222's are NPN transistors. The schematic shows them as PNPs. IRF630's are MOSFETs. The schematic shows them as BJTs. Even if this circuit works, the output voltage will depend upon the transformer, which has been given no specifications.

Comment: Also, the transformer won't do anything, as only one end of each winding is connected.  There is no indication of where a load would be connected.

Answer (score 1):

There are few things that *aren't* wrong with this circuit. I strongly suggest you not use it for anything that actually matters.

That said, **as an academic exercise only**, let's go over the problems with how it's drawn first.

1. The wrong symbols are used for all the transistors.

   - The 2N2222 is an NPN BJT, but is drawn using the symbol for a PNP BJT. A PNP would not work here.
   - The IRF630 is an n-channel MOSFET, but is also drawn using the symbol for a PNP BJT. A PNP would not work here either, though an NPN BJT might.

     - Additionally, it's IRF630, not IRF 630.
2. The transformer is drawn wrong.

   - The transformer shows one connection to the primary, one connection to the secondary, and one connection to the core (!?).

     - The correct way to connect it would be to draw two connections to the primary. The core should not be connected to anything. See below for what this is probably intended to be.
3. The units are wrong and inconsistent.

   - It's 12 kΩ, not 12K Ohm or 12k Ohm.
   - It's 2.2 μF, not 2.2 Uf. (2.2 uF would also be acceptable. Uf is definitely not.)
   - It's 50 V, not 50V.
4. The wires are laid out poorly and it's hard to see what's what.

   - Crossings are not correctly marked; everywhere wires cross, there should be a dot if they are meant to connect. There are several points where it's clear they're supposed to connect, but they are not shown as connected.

     - There are also a few points where it's clear they're *not* supposed to connect, but these are drawn identically to the ones where they *are*.
   - There's no reason for the wires to loop around the two left transistors. Flip the transistor symbols horizontally so they don't have to.
5. All the labels are positioned poorly.

   - The resistor values are overlapping the resistors.
   - The transistor labels are inconsistently positioned and at times quite far from the transistors.
6. The transformer and battery are completely unlabelled.

   - This is self-explanatory. How are you to know what transformer ratio to use? What battery voltage to use?

(I'll include a more appropriately drawn version of this circuit later, when CircuitLab starts working again)

What this circuit is probably *intended* to be is a two-transistor oscillator (aka astable multivibrator) driving MOSFET switches that alternately pull down one side or the other of a center-tapped transformer primary whose center-tap is connected to the DC supply voltage. This is what's called a push-pull converter, and such a device *can* be used as a crude inverter. However, when driving it with just a two-transistor oscillator like this, the frequency and duty cycle are not stable (both will vary a lot with temperature) and the drive strength is poor; the FETs won't turn on very quickly (though they will turn off quickly).

A better way to make a circuit like this would use a stable oscillator as your frequency reference, and proper gate drivers for the transistors. Additionally, the choice of transistor is a bit excessive--the IRF630 is rated for 200 volts and 9 amps, and it's *very* unlikely you're using a 200 V battery here (not to mention that would destroy the capacitors).

Which is all a very long way to say, you probably shouldn't trust any other circuits you find on that site. This one had no chance of ever working.

Comment: If the circuit works, it will produce squarewaves not normal electricity sinewaves.

Comment: @Audioguru That's not necessarily a problem. There are many other things wrong with this circuit, but I wouldn't consider that one of them without knowing more about what specifically it's being used to supply.